# Displaying all thread groups and threads currently running in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-threads

So my task is to display all thread groups and all threads belonging to these groups currently running within the JVM.

This should be outputted so that the thread group is displayed first and then all the treads in this group are displayed underneath. This is done for all thread groups. Currently my code will just display every thread groups and then every thread but I am unsure how to reach the output I have described.

Here is my current code:

```
public  ThreadGroup getThreadRoot() {
    ThreadGroup rootGroup = Thread.currentThread( ).getThreadGroup( );
    ThreadGroup parentGroup;
    while ( ( parentGroup = rootGroup.getParent() ) != null ) {
        rootGroup = parentGroup;
    }
    return rootGroup;
}

public  ThreadGroup[] getAllThreadGroups(){


    ThreadGroup root= getThreadRoot();
    int estimate = root.activeGroupCount();
    ThreadGroup [] threads = new ThreadGroup[estimate];
    while ( root.enumerate( threads, true ) == threads.length ) {
        threads = new ThreadGroup[ threads.length * 2 ];
    }


    ThreadGroup[] allGroups = new ThreadGroup[threads.length+1];
    allGroups[0] = root;
    System.arraycopy( threads, 0, allGroups, 1, estimate );
    return allGroups;

}
public Thread[] getAllThreads(){

     ThreadGroup root= getThreadRoot();
     int estimate = root.activeGroupCount();
     Thread [] allThreads = new Thread[estimate];
     while ( root.enumerate( allThreads, true ) == allThreads.length ) {
         allThreads = new Thread[ allThreads.length * 2 ];
     }


     return allThreads;

}
```

and the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {

    CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
    Functionality func = new Functionality();
    ThreadGroup[] tg = func.getAllThreadGroups();
    Thread[] t = func.getAllThreads();
    for (int i=0; i<tg.length; i++) {
        if(tg[i] != null){
        System.out.println("Name: " + tg[i].getName());
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
        if(t[i] != null){
        System.out.println("Name: " + t[i].getName() + ", id: " + t[i].getId() 
                + ", State: " + t[i].getState() + ", Is daemon? " + t[i].isDaemon());
        }
}
}

}
```

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts. It's a well-written, decently thought-out, legitimate question; why would you delete its content? Additionally, Stack Exchange holds full ownership over anything you post on it so you're not allowed to vandalize your own posts in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for the simplest solution to get a hierarchical output of all thread groups and threads, you only need your `getThreadRoot()` method:

```
Functionality func = new Functionality();
func.getThreadRoot().list();
```

however, it will print even the groups hierarchical rather than a list of groups with only the threads as children. For this, you have to *nest* your loops, i.e.

```
CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
Functionality func = new Functionality();
ThreadGroup[] tg = func.getAllThreadGroups();
Thread[] t = func.getAllThreads();
for(int i=0; i<tg.length; i++) {
    if(tg[i] != null) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + tg[i].getName());
        for(int j=0; j<t.length; j++) {
            if(t[j] != null && t[j].getThreadGroup() == tg[i]) {
            System.out.println("    Name: " + t[j].getName() + ", id: " + t[j].getId() 
                    + ", State: " + t[j].getState() + ", Is daemon? " + t[j].isDaemon());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a reference comparison in the inner loop, to only show the threads of the current group. More efficient would be to only get threads of the current group in the first place, i.e. add a method to your `Functionality`:

```
public Thread[] getThreadsOf(ThreadGroup group) {
    int estimate = group.activeCount();
    Thread[] groupThreads = new Thread[estimate];
    while(group.enumerate( groupThreads, false ) == groupThreads.length) {
        groupThreads = new Thread[ groupThreads.length * 2 ];
    }
    return groupThreads;
}
```

and change the caller to

```
CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
Functionality func = new Functionality();
ThreadGroup[] tg = func.getAllThreadGroups();
for(int i=0; i<tg.length; i++) {
    if(tg[i] != null) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + tg[i].getName());
        Thread[] t = func.getThreadsOf(tg[i]);
        for(int j=0; j<t.length; j++) {
            if(t[j] != null) {
            System.out.println("    Name: " + t[j].getName() + ", id: " + t[j].getId() 
                    + ", State: " + t[j].getState() + ", Is daemon? " + t[j].isDaemon());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, since Java 5, this can be nicely written as

```
CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
Functionality func = new Functionality();
for(ThreadGroup tg: func.getAllThreadGroups()) {
    if(tg != null) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + tg.getName());
        for(Thread t: func.getThreadsOf(tg)) {
            if(t != null) {
                System.out.println("    Name: " + t.getName() + ", id: " + t.getId() 
                    + ", State: " + t.getState() + ", Is daemon? " + t.isDaemon());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But note that these old `enumerate` methods are highly discouraged. They are not only complicated to use, the result is error prone due to the fact that the threads and groups may change while you are processing them. It’s much simpler and more reliable to work on a single snapshot made at one point of time:

```
CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
Map<ThreadGroup, List<Thread>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Thread thread: Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    List<Thread> list = map.get(thread.getThreadGroup());
    if(list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(thread.getThreadGroup(), list);
    }
    list.add(thread);
}


for(Map.Entry<ThreadGroup,List<Thread>> groupEntry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + groupEntry.getKey().getName());
    for(Thread thread: groupEntry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("    Name: " + thread.getName() + ", id: " + thread.getId() 
            + ", State: " + thread.getState() + ", Is daemon? " + thread.isDaemon());
    }
}
```

This logic becomes even simpler when using Java 8 features:

```
CreateDummyGroups create = new CreateDummyGroups();
Map<ThreadGroup, List<Thread>> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
    .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Thread::getThreadGroup));


map.forEach((group,threadList) -> {
    System.out.println("Name: " + group.getName());
    threadList.forEach(thread -> 
        System.out.println("    Name: " + thread.getName() + ", id: " + thread.getId() 
            + ", State: " + thread.getState() + ", Is daemon? " + thread.isDaemon())
    );
});
```

Comment: @j4nbur53 keep in mind that the number of threads can change in between anyway and you have to recheck the number returned by `enumerate`. But there is no way to distinguish the case that the number of threads matches the array length and the case that the array was too small. So the loop will *always* run until the array is larger than the actual number of threads. So it’s not bad to use a number potentially larger than the threads in the group as a starting point. It’s a horrible legacy API…

Comment: I just wonder who designed the ThreadGroup API, inside the ThreadGroup I find a very nice snapshot functions, used by all of the methods, even based on Array.copy, but its not exposed since the fields are package local. You basically suggest two different workarounds, so I wonder whether there are even other solutions, maybe poke the fields via reflection. But other JVMs might not have these fields.

Comment: @j4nbur53 I suppose, the code looked entirely different back then when it was designed (back in Java 1.0). So the developers did consider that it all was a big mistake but has to be kept for compatibility, but did not improve it in any way (regarding the public API). Internally, it has been retrofitted to use newer facilities (`Arrays.copyOf` exists since Java 6).

Comment: Very funny turn of events. Finnally, in the app I have, I only needed Thread[] threads=new Thread[1], tg.enumerate(threads, false). So one by one picking the oldest thread. And the day zero API seems to be efficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to get all threads is to use ThreadMXBean:

```
ThreadMXBean thbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
final long[] ids = thbean.getAllThreadIds();
```

From there you can get all kind of information, see also:

https://github.com/liguobing/ToolCode/blob/master/ThreadUtilities.java

But unfortunately ThreadMXBean is not directly available on Android.