# How to get the number of current worker threads in a JVM threadpool?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am using the threadpool classes in java Base class library. Specifically `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` etc.

In my application i want to log metrics on how many threads are running (actually doing user supplied work) vs waiting for work.

I looked at the hooks provided by the classes, but could not find any way to do it.

I can of course implement something like that by putting my work unit in the worker thread around a `try/finally` and incrementing/decrementing a global counter. But was wondering if there was something out of the box that i am missing.

Comment: I think you may find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959700/displaying-all-thread-groups-and-threads-currently-running-in-jvm

Comment: Or in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get total number of threads:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```